# Azure Function silently fails to start if dependency is misconfigured

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

When developing locally on my machine, if I do not start the Azure Cosmos Emulator, my Function fails to start correctly. There are no errors in the console output, however if I try to call a HttpTrigger function the TCP connection is refused. No exceptions are trapped by the Visual Studio debugger, and no errors are shown in the console.

How can I get an error to be logged to console?

The only difference I've seen is in the console output is the following output **not** showing when Cosmos is switched off:

```
[2020-10-19T19:20:29.487] Host started (2444ms)
[2020-10-19T19:20:29.490] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Code\MyApp.Functions\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[2020-10-19T19:20:34.554] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000C51E9459'.
```

I'm not seeing much when using enhanced logging either, as configured below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Host.Triggers.Warmup": "Trace",
      "Host.General": "Trace",
      "Host": "Trace",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "MyApp": "Trace",
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is a diff of the logs after normalizing meaningless differences, including timestamps, guids and execution-times.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the log level to Trace? It should provide more details.

Comment: Yes (I've updated the question description now), while it does result in more logging, the differences remain the same.

Comment: can you please clarify what means 'more logging' but 'remains the same'.. Can you please share what do you see?

Comment: There's 450 lines of logging so I didn't want to include it all. I've updated the problem-description with a screenshot of the differences. To clarify, there's more logging using Trace than Debug, but despite that, the only differences are the same differences as before.

Comment: The error would happen on the first attempt to call the HttpTrigger, can you show which is the current log entries for that? And what is missing there?